# Microsoft Bot Framework - Multi turn context is lost after the first interaction

Tags: frameworks, bots

I recently moved my code from SDK v3 to v4 and I am trying to take advantage of the multi-turn features.

I have looked over the samples from GitHub. The samples work well for multi-turn but one issue I noticed is that it recognizes the context only if the prompt is clicked immediately after the initial answer (with prompts) is shown.
I would like to be able to identify, at any given time that a prompt is clicked. I am storing all the previous prompts in the state object (`dialogInstance.State`) already. I have a custom host, which sends the replytoid and using that I can get the appropriate state.

The problem is though, I am not able to get to a point where I can use the `dialoginstance.State`.

The sample code uses the DialogExtensions class. The "DialogExtensions" class tries to gather the previous context by checking if the result from the `ContinueDialogAsync` method returns null or not.

[DialogExtensions class with multi-turn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKv97.png)

When there is no previous context (no previous answer with prompts), then the call to the ContinueDialogAsync returns a result with Empty Status.

I am thinking this where I need to check the `dialogstate` and if the new message refers to any of the old messages at any given point, it can then start to continue the old conversation.

I am not sure if that is even possible.
Any help/pointers would be appreciated.
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up implementing something that will work for custom bot host/direct channel bot client.

The whole point is that the call to the qnamaker api should happen with the old context object, whenever an option is chosen, even if it is out-of-context.

First let me explain how it works in the current version of the code.
The way the bot code was trying to solve multi turn dialog, was by storing the current answer if it had prompts/options and returning the conversation state in "waiting" mode. When the next question is received, it would automatically assume that the new question is part of the prompts/options of the old question. It would then pass the oldstate along to the QnAMaker. 
What I noticed is that, even if the question in the second turn is not part of the prompts/options (something the user has typed manually and is a completely different question), it would still send the oldstate object to the QnAMaker.
The QnAMaker api call seem to ignore oldstate if the new question is not part of the prompts/options of the oldstate. It will work correctly by fetching the answer for the new question that was typed manually.
This was the key. If we can focus on what gets to the qnamaker then we can solve our original problem.

I realized that having the bot return a waiting state is only a mechanism to create a condition to extract the oldstate in the next turn. However, if I can rebuild the oldstate anytime when there is an option chosen, then the call to the qnamaker would work equally well.

This is what I have done now. 
In my custom bot host code (which is a direct line client), I am sending the ReplyToID field populated with the original question whenever a prompt is clicked. Then in the bot code, I have changed it so that if there is a replytoid present, then build a new oldstate object with the data from the reply to id. Below is the QnABotState class that represents the oldstate. its a very simple class containing previous qna question id and the question text.

```
public int PreviousQnaId { get; set; }

public string PreviousUserQuery { get; set; }
```

[QnABoState class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZhkE.png)

Now, the problem was the Activity object contains ReplyToId but does not contain ReplyToQuery (or something like that). Activity object is used to send data from bot client to the bot. So, either I would have to use a different field or send the PreviousUserQuery as an empty string. I had a hunch that it would work with just the previousqnaid.

```
//starting the process to get the old context (create an object that will hold the Process function's current state from the dialog state)
            //if there is replyToId field is present, then it is a direct channel request who is replying to an old context
            //get the reply to id from summary field
            var curReplyToId = "";            
            curReplyToId = dialogContext.Context.Activity.ReplyToId;
            var curReplyToQuery = "";



            var oldState = GetPersistedState(dialogContext.ActiveDialog);

            //if oldstate is null also check if there is replytoid populated, if it is then it maybe a new conversation but it is actually an "out of turn option" selection.
            if (oldState == null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(curReplyToId))
                {
                    //curReplyToId is not empty. this is an option that was selected out-of-context
                    int prevQnaId = -1;
                    int.TryParse(curReplyToId, out prevQnaId);

                    oldState = new QnABotState() { PreviousQnaId = prevQnaId, PreviousUserQuery = curReplyToQuery };
                }

            }
```

With that in place, my call to the qnamaker api would receive an oldstate object even if it is called out-of-context.

I tried the code and it worked. Not having the previous qna query did not make a difference. It worked with just the PreviousQnaId field being populated.

However, please note, this will not work for other channels. It would work for channels where you can set the ReplyToId field, such as the Direct Channel Client.

here is the code from my bot host:

```
  // to create a new message
    Activity userMessage = new Activity
    {
        From = new ChannelAccount(User.Identity.Name),
        Text = questionToBot,
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Value = paramChatCode,// + "|" + "ShahID-" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
        Id = "ShahID-" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
        ChannelData = botHostId//this will be added as the bot host identifier
    };
    //userMessage.Type = "imBack";
    if (paramPreviousChatId > 0)
    {
        //we have a valid replytoid (as a part of dialog)
        userMessage.ReplyToId = paramPreviousChatId.ToString();

    }
```